# django admin not showing project

Tags: django-admin

Hi I'm sure i am doing something dumb! Fairly new to django and pycharm. I am learning by writing two projects: the tango with django one and another to test ideas and learning (about old girlfriends!).

I am working on the rango project. I've scheme-migrated, syncdb, migrate, debugged and no errors. But when i run server, the admin page shows the other project only. I have not worked on it today.

As far as I can tell I have all the right code including registering the models and admin.autodiscover plus i have cleared the cache.

SO the question is: **which projects does it show on the admin page - all? How does it know?**

Final odd point the windows circle on the site admin tab is still going round as though its looking for something else.

Many thanks for help. I haven't pasted any code as not sure what would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually realized that the admin server was still running. As laptops don't have a ctrl break key (and i couldn't find my Samsung mapping) i killed the server using task manager and all was fine.